# how to use same links to images and files - on local and remote server

Tags: php, localhost, remote-server

I'm working on a site with a lot of subdomains
and want to share some `images`, `css` and `js` files between domain and subdomains
and want to have entire site on my localhost - `win10, xampp, chrome`
problem - cannot use the same paths - because `example.com` on remote server is a domain - and on localhost - it is just a folder
my solution is like this:

```
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if(str_contains($url, 'localhost')){$host = 'local';}
else{$host = 'remote';}

if($host == 'local'){$path = '...';}  // a relative path
else{$path = '...';}  // an absolute path to another subdomain

<img src = "<?php echo $path; ?>" alt='img'>
```

this works but is very tedious - for each image and/or file

question - is there a better way to solve the above

if not - is it possible to have entire local server identically the same as a remote one - with real domains and subdomains (on local level) - instead of folders

Comment: Have you taken a look into Apaches Virtual Host Feature combined with a modified Version of your hosts file (residing in C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc)?

Both together give you a very flexible way of simulating domain-like structures on a local level.

Comment: @mynd - maybe my real question should be - do I need localhost at all. What about using a separate remote (sub)domain as a testing environment?

Comment: This depends on personal preference I guess. However, to tackle your problem independently from this question, I would implement a function like ` getFilePath($fileName)` that wraps your described logic from above and then use the returned path, e.g. `<img src=" <?php echo getFilePath('logo.jpg')?>"....`

Comment: @mynd - can't find - `getFilePath` - give me reference link, pls

Comment: `getFilePath` is a custom function that you should declare yourself based on the logic you have provided for alternating the file paths. It is not a default function. I just wanted to give you an idea on how you could determine the actual filepath with regards to brevity and re-usage of code. Hope that clarifies my intention.

Comment: sounds as a nonsense. Argument for that function must be the path, nothing else

Comment: Based on the information you have provided this is most likely wrong. However, good luck with finding a solution.